# Enable button on select of treeveiw root node

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a Tree View

```
<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tvLocations" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

And a button

```
        <Button Name="cmdUpdateLocation" Grid.Row="1" Content="Update" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,88,0">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tvLocations, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

This will enable the button no matter what level of the tree they click on. I want to enable the button when an item in the tree view is selected but only if it is the root node or disable the button if it is not the root. Can I detect in XAML if the node they have selected is the root node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not directly. If your `TreeView.Items` are of type `TreeViewItem` you could use the solution described here: [WPF Treeview root node](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/wpf-treeview-root-node/).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tvLocations, Path=SelectedItem.(local:MyTreeView.IsRootNode)}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If your `TreeView.Items` are of any other type I think you have to implement an additional IsRootNode property for your items.

Comment: Thanks LPL, it seems odd to me that there is no built in property to determine a root node.  However I have done as you suggested and implemented my own IsRootNode property.  Interesting blog btw.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an alternate solution that does not require code behind.  Use a trigger with a binding that looks for an ancestor of the TreeViewItem type and triggers when it equals {x:Null}.  This will fire for the root node as it has no TreeViewItem ancestor.  The following example trigger prevents the root node from being collapsed:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="ItemsHost" />
</DataTrigger>
```